# Некорректная работа функции Sleep()

Tags: c++builder, c++

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой работы функции `Sleep()`, приведу пример в наипростейшем цикле (в моей программе Слип встроена в цикл), при нажатии на кнопку выполняется цикл:

```
{
  for (i<0;i<10;i++) 
  {
    Label->Caption=IntToStr(i);
    Sleep(1000);
  };
}
```

По идее, `Label1` должен менять значение от 0 до 9 с интервалом в 1 сек, однако при нажатии программа "засыпает" на 9 сек и `Label1` сразу принимает значение 9, в чем может быть проблема? МБ существует другой способ сделать обновление поля метки с временным интервалом?

Comment: Не сталкивался с c++builder ни разу, но самая первая гипотеза -- требуется принудительное обновление экрана. Менять-то оно меняет, только вот отрисовывать ей не до сук. Какой метод какого класса вызывает отрисовку (refresh) -- понятия не имею. Но должен быть.

Comment: Если вместо Sleep написать ShowMessage, то он 10 раз покажет сообщение и при этом будет менять значение лэйбла) дело не в обнове экрана)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не забавное поведение. А абсолютно правильное и штатное. Sleep останавливает текущий поток. А так как текущий поток кроме всего прочего занимается обновлением окна, то ему просто некогда это делать.  `Application.ProcessMessages();` как раз выгребает с очереди сообщений сообщения и обрабатывает их.

Если нужно сделать обновления с интервалом, то следует использовать либо таймер, либо поток. А Sleep в главном треде использовать только в самую последнюю очередь.

Answer (score 1):

Нужная процедура в Delphi называется `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: Спасибо) Помогло) А разницы особой в функциях нету что С, что в Делфе, ото одного разработчика продукты)